# MongoDB - upgrade from 3.2 to 3.4

Tags: mongodb

I updated with this commands from MongoDB 3.2 to 3.4:

```
https://medium.com/mongoaudit/how-to-upgrade-mongodb-to-latest-stable- version-9607266834cf:
sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb*.list
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv 0C49F3730359A14518585931BC711F9BA15703C6
echo "deb http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu xenial/mongodb-org/3.4 multiverse" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-3.4.list
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y mongodb-org
```

sudo apt-get install -y mongodb-org shows this lines:

```
root@accounting:/home/accounting# sudo apt-get install -y mongodb-org
Paketlisten werden gelesen... Fertig
Abhängigkeitsbaum wird aufgebaut.       
Statusinformationen werden eingelesen.... Fertig
»mongodb-org« ist bereits die neuste Version (3.4.17).
```

Afterwards I started mongo and the following lines are shown:

```
root@accounting:/home/accounting# mongo
MongoDB shell version: 3.2.17
```

How can I update MongoDB shell version to 3.4.17?

**[SOLVED]**

```
sudo service mongod stop
sudo apt-get purge mongodb-org*
mongod --shutdown
```